# Can ping/nmap server, nothing else

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ping

I was SSHed into our ubuntu LAMP server , and was just doing a svn update, which hung.

I disconnected, and since then, I have not been able to SSH in or view any of our websites (neither from my network or through a remote machine).

I would have just assumed the server went down, but I can ping the machine and get really quick responses. Using nmap on the box shows all the normal ports open, so I am confused

This server is hosted remotely in a datacenter, do I have any remaining options except contacting them for support? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bummer.  Maybe you'll get lucky and find that the svn update was just killing your virtual memory and things will recover.

If not, you're probably going to have to engage support.  I would recommend getting some sort of KVM-over-IP or serial console installed to help out with this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it's run out of memory, which means that the OOM-Killer has gone around wiping out processes, presumably it's got bad enough that it's killed something like init or sshd which means you now can't login - the Kernel (which handles ICMP responses) is resident in memory and not affected by OOM-Killer so it's still responding to that.

All you can probably do is to get on there and reboot it, does your server have remote reboots? If not, then contact support.

There is a chance it'll come back if the OOM-Killer works as it's supposed to, but if it's not back now after 5 hours then it's probably not going to come back.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not reconnect via SSH then your only option is to contact the hosting company and have them do a hard power cycle on the machine.